# How can I use a variable value from a project inside of a Exec task in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to write an exec task in gradle that would use a variable set on the project.

Something like so:

```
task upload(type: Exec) {
   executable "echo"
   args version
}
```

This always gives me "unspecified"

If I do a task like this

```
task upload <<  {
   println version
}
```

It will print the value of the *version* variable

How can I use the value of *version* inside an Exec task ?

Comment: Where are you defining `version`? The difference between those two examples is one is evaluated at configuration time and the other during execution. Depending on how you are declaring that variable could determine its usage.

Comment: Which one is evaluated at configuration time? I'm still confused by the configuration time vs. execution. Why is one evaluated at configuration time and the other at execution time?

version is set in a method incrementVersion() that is called using gradle.taskGraph.whenReady   which I believe is run after configuration.

Comment: The former is executed at configuration time. You are "configuring" the `Exec` task, therefore this code is executed during script evaluation (before any tasks are run). In the second example you are using the left shift operator (<<) to add a task action to the task `upload`. This action is evaluated during execution time (when the task actually runs). Since you are defining the variable rather late in the configuration phase (after the task graph has been populated), it is not available for use during the configuration phase.

Comment: Is there a good resource that explains the difference between configuring a task and adding a task action? I've read http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html and also chapter 15 - but obviously I'm not getting it.

Comment: There is some explanation of the build phases in the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases). The thing to keep in mind is typically when you are defining your own task, or adding an action to a task using methods like `doLast`, that code is being run during execution. In basically all other cases, the code in your build script is configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Mark Vieira

I found that writing my own task that calls the exec task works the way I need it to.

Like so

```
task upload << {
    exec {
     executable "echo"
     args version
    }
}
```